# Porting openGL calls to shaders results in 2D ortho not working as expected anymore

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

## Further Details

I am trying to render a texture in 2D using OpenGL and encountering some problems with the orthogonal projection matrix:
[image: RenderResult]

Its pretty much just a straightforward port of the old code using the GL functions thus I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here that I get a strangely stretched output from a plane

Thus the question is: how can I get it "flattened" to a 2D level that I'm able to draw a 2D texture again?

I already tried to change the matrix to a perspective which resulted in showing nothing

Adding a view matrix to change the angle also did not helped

X39

## The Code & Shaders

### VAO generation

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &texture2D_vao);
glBindVertexArray(texture2D_vao);

GLuint vertBufferID, indexBufferID;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertBufferID);
glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);

struct Vec2 { float x, y; };
struct Vec3 { float x, y, z; };
struct Vert { Vec3 pos; Vec2 tex; };

std::array<Vert, 4>  verts = { {
    { { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f } },
    { { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 0.0f } },
    { { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f } },
    { { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f } }
    } };

std::array<unsigned int, 6> indexies = { { 0, 1, 2, 3} };

// Vertex buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vert) * verts.size(), verts.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Matches layout (location = 0)
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vert), 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); // Matches layout (location = 1)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vert), (GLvoid*)sizeof(Vec3));

// Index buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * indexies.size(), indexies.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

### Draw Function

```
void GuiBase::drawTexture2D(::X39::Singletons::MATERIAL* mat, unsigned int textureIndex, double tPosX, double tPosY, double tWidth, double tHeight, double uiPosX, double uiPosY, double uiWidth, double uiHeight, Shader& shad)
{
    ::X39::Singletons::TEXTURE* texture = mat->textures[textureIndex];
    ::X39::Singletons::MaterialManager::getInstance().loadMaterial(mat, textureIndex);

    ::glm::mat4 scaleMatrix = ::glm::scale(::glm::mat4(1.0f), ::glm::vec3((float)uiWidth, (float)uiHeight, 1.0f));
    std::array<float, 6> uvManipulation = { tPosX, tPosY, tWidth, tHeight, texture->width, texture->height };
    glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::ortho(
        (float)0,
        (float)::X39::GlobalObject::getInstance().render_width / (float)::X39::GlobalObject::getInstance().render_height,
        (float)0,
        (float)::X39::GlobalObject::getInstance().render_height / (float)::X39::GlobalObject::getInstance().render_width,
        0.0f,
        100.0f
        );

    glBindVertexArray(texture2D_vao);

    shad.setUniformMatrix4fv("scaleMatrix", 1, GL_FALSE, &scaleMatrix[0][0], -1);
    shad.setUniformMatrix4fv("projectionMatrix", 1, GL_FALSE, &projectionMatrix[0][0], -1);
    shad.setUniform1fv("UV_Manipulators", 6, uvManipulation.data(), -1);
    shad.setUniform3fv("worldPosition", 1, &glm::vec3(
        uiPosX,
        uiPosY,
        0
        )[0], -1);
    shad.setUniform1i("textureSampler", texture->textureUnit, -1);
    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);


}
```

### Vertex Shader

```
#version 440


layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV_modelspace;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 scaleMatrix;
uniform vec3 worldPosition;

out vec2 UV;
uniform float[6] UV_Manipulators;


void main()
{
    gl_Position = scaleMatrix * vec4((vertexPosition_modelspace + worldPosition), 1) * projectionMatrix;
    vec2 newUV = vertexUV_modelspace;
    if(newUV.x > 0)
    {
        newUV.x = (UV_Manipulators[0] + UV_Manipulators[2]) / UV_Manipulators[4];
    }
    else
    {
        newUV.x = (UV_Manipulators[0]) / UV_Manipulators[4];
    }
    if(newUV.y > 0)
    {
        newUV.y = (UV_Manipulators[1] + UV_Manipulators[3]) / UV_Manipulators[5];
    }
    else
    {
        newUV.y = (UV_Manipulators[1]) / UV_Manipulators[5];
    }
    UV = newUV;
}
```

Comment: Most likely not the problem, but indexies has only 4 elements but you declare it as having 6 and pass in 6 to glDrawElements. GL_QUADS is deprecated in new versions of OpenGL, try using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and passing in a count of 4

Comment: I haven't read it in full, but should it be `gl_Position = projectionMatrix * scaleMatrix * vec4(...)`? Also why not combine `scaleMatrix` and `worldPosition` into a single modelview matrix? You could also introduce a texture matrix rather than the single purpose `UV_Manipulators`.

Comment: Can you post an image of the expected result? Just to be sure.

Comment: arg ... its rly been the order (such a stupid mistake) ...

`gl_Position = projectionMatrix * scaleMatrix * vec4(...)`

works fine like it should
thx @jozxyqk (if you could post it as answere so i can mark it it would be great)

the reason why currently everything is kinda messed up is because it is not cleaned up yet due to the fact that the current stuff im doing is not done yet